# Python extract string starting with index up to character

Tags: python, string, substring, extract

Say I have an incoming string that varies a little:

1. `"  1 |r|=1.2e10 |v|=2.4e10"`
2. `" 12 |r|=-2.3e10 |v|=3.5e-04"`
3. `"134 |r|= 3.2e10 |v|=4.3e05"`

I need to extract the numbers (ie. 1.2e10, 3.5e-04, etc)... so I would like to start at the end of '|r|' and grab all characters up to the ' ' (space) after it. Same for '|v|'

I've been looking for something that would:
Extract a substring form a string starting at an index and ending on a specific character...
But have not found anything remotely close.
Ideas?

NOTE: Added new scenario, which is the one that is causing lots of head-scratching...

Comment: So you want to extract the numbers? You could split the string at the `=`, then again at the spaces.Can you give your desired output?

Comment: _"I need to extract the '5678'"_ — I'm confused because '5678' does not appear in your examples. What does this even mean?

Comment: Edited with extra scenario and updated the desired output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep it elegant and generic, let's utilize [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

1. First, we split by ' ' to tokens
2. Then we find if it has an equal sign and parse the key-value

```
import re
sabich = "134 |r|     = 3.2e10 |v|=4.3e05"

parts = sabich.split(' |')
values = {}
for p in parts:
    if '=' in p:
        k, v = p.split('=')
        values[k.replace('|', '').strip()] = v.strip(' ')

# {'r': '3.2e10', 'v': '4.3e05'}
print(values)
```

This can be converted to the one-liner:

```
import re
sabich = "134 |r|     = 3.2e10 |v|=4.3e05"

values = {t[0].replace('|', '').strip() :  t[1].strip(' ') for t in [tuple(p.split('=')) for p in sabich.split(' |') if '=' in p]}

# {'|r|': '1.2e10', '|v|': '2.4e10'}
print(values)
```

Comment: Nice! I like returning the values as a dict.

Comment: Thank you @rcriii :)

Comment: Edited my question with one other scenario... which makes splitting on a 'space' character an issue... the extra space can be for any of the || items (and there may be 20+ of those items per string)

Comment: Although I did not use your solution, it was the best option for more complex parsing in my situation. However, you did point me in the right direction. Dumb Blonde move on my part, I ended up just doing a replace on the '= '...

Comment: Thank you @SamGrant!

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it with a regular expression.

```
import re

strings = [
    "  1 |r|=1.2e10 |v|=2.4e10",
    " 12 |r|=-2.3e10 |v|=3.5e-04"
]

out = []
pattern = r'(?P<name>\|[\w]+\|)=(?P<value>-?\d+(?:\.\d*)(?:e-?\d*)?)'
for s in strings:
    out.append(dict(re.findall(pattern, s)))

print(out)
```

Output

```
[{'|r|': '1.2e10', '|v|': '2.4e10'}, {'|r|': '-2.3e10', '|v|': '3.5e-04'}]
```

And if you want to convert the strings to number

```
out = []
pattern = r'(?P<name>\|[\w]+\|)=(?P<value>-?\d+(?:\.\d*)(?:e-?\d*)?)'
for s in strings:
    # out.append(dict(re.findall(pattern, s)))
    out.append({
        name: float(value)
        for name, value in re.findall(pattern, s)
    })
```

Output

```
[{'|r|': 12000000000.0, '|v|': 24000000000.0}, {'|r|': -23000000000.0, '|v|': 0.00035}]
```